# Android, Dialog interface doesn't show when I post message to Facebook?

Tags: android, facebook, sdk, sharing

Through Facebook SDK I'm sharing a message to Facebook. I can share my message successfully, however I don't see any dialog for log-in and post message. When I click on my share button my  message will be post to Facebook without dialog interface. So, how to show dialog box and let my user to click on post button?

This is mt code:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       Log.i(TAG, "Try to create activity...");

       mFacebook = new Facebook(FACEBOOK_APPID);
       mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(mFacebook);

       if(!restoreCredentials(mFacebook)) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Try to get token...");
            mFacebook.authorize(this, PERMISSIONS, Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH, new LoginDialogListener());
        }

        postFacebookMessage();
    }
```

//

```
private void postFacebookMessage() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Try to post message");

        token = mFacebook.getAccessToken();
        Log.i("token", "" + token);

        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("access_token", token);
        parameters.putString("message", "Text is test message.");
        parameters.putString("name", "Chef Astro");
        parameters.putString("link", "http://www.astrogempak.com.my");
        parameters.putString("caption", "Caption");
        parameters.putString("description", message);
        parameters.putString("picture","http://a1.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple/v4/2d/7d/c3/2d7dc3ed-9e32-cd7b-adba-2a31637a8cf0/mzl.toeyydsk.175x175-75.jpg");

        mAsyncRunner.request("me/feed", parameters, "POST", new WallPostRequestListener(), null); 
    }
```

//

```
class LoginDialogListener implements DialogListener {

    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
        saveCredentials(mFacebook);
        Log.i(TAG, "Credentials saved.");
    }

    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
        showToast("Authentication with Facebook failed!");
    }

    public void onError(DialogError error) {
        showToast("Authentication with Facebook failed!");
    }

    public void onCancel() {
        showToast("Authentication with Facebook cancelled!");
    }
}
```

//

```
public boolean saveCredentials(Facebook facebook) {
    Editor editor = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putString(TOKEN, facebook.getAccessToken());
    editor.putLong(EXPIRES, facebook.getAccessExpires());
    return editor.commit();
}

public boolean restoreCredentials(Facebook facebook) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    facebook.setAccessToken(sharedPreferences.getString(TOKEN, null));
    facebook.setAccessExpires(sharedPreferences.getLong(EXPIRES, 0));

    return facebook.isSessionValid();
}
```

//

```
public class WallPostRequestListener extends BaseRequestListener {
    public void onComplete(final String response, final Object state) {
        Log.d("Facebook-Example", "Got response: " + response);
        String message = "<empty>";
        try {
            JSONObject json = Util.parseJson(response);
            message = json.getString("message");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.w("Facebook-Example", "JSON Error in response");
        } catch (FacebookError e) {
            Log.w("Facebook-Example", "Facebook Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        final String text = "Your Wall Post: " + message;
        FacebookActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Log.d(TAG, text);
            }
        });

        closeActivity();
    }
}
```

In above code I expect when the dialog displays user can write his/her suggestion in text box and I get it here.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Are you using native SDK of Facebook for Android?.If yes then read this tutorial. This tutorial explain all the Facebook dialog for android  with proper example.

[FaceBook Tutorial Link :](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/)

Comment: thanks, dear Rishabah. Yes, I read that document and my code is based on its example in its SDK. However, I doesn't show the dialog interface.

Comment: some phone doesnot show dialogbox this is bug in facebook andrioid sdk.kindly use some other phone for test your code.

Comment: Thanks dear Rishabh. Actually I solved this problem with replaying mAsyncRunner.request(...) line with mAsyncRunner.request(...) but I have another problem. please see my next question at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453347/android-how-to-fit-message-in-facebook-dialog