# Android, How to fit message in Facebook dialog?

Tags: android, facebook, dialog, screen

After two days of searching finally I could integrate Facebook SDK into my application. My problem is when I set bundle and show dialog interface, some parts of lines are out of screen. This is my code:

```
        private void postFacebookMessage() {
            Log.i(TAG, "Try to post message");

            token = mFacebook.getAccessToken();
            Log.i("token", "" + token);

            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("access_token", token);
            parameters.putString("message", "This is test message.");
            parameters.putString("name", "Chef Astro");
            parameters.putString("link", "http://www.astrogempak.com.my");
            parameters.putString("caption", message);
            parameters.putString("description", "");
            parameters.putString("picture","http://a1.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple/v4/2d/7d/c3/2d7dc3ed-9e32-cd7b-adba-2a31637a8cf0/mzl.toeyydsk.175x175-75.jpg");

    //      mAsyncRunner.request("me/feed", parameters, "POST", new WallPostRequestListener(), null); 
            mFacebook.dialog(FacebookActivity.this, "feed", parameters, new SampleDialogListener());
    }
```

I put `message` in `description` but result is same. How to fit message inside dialog?
[image]

Comment: Can you show the Picture of Dialog you are getting?

Comment: Hi Venky, which picture you mean? it's been attached to my question. your browser doesn't show it?

Comment: I think so, i coudn't see any images attached here :(

Comment: it's been attached below of my code. please test it on other browser if you can. Thanks :)